# How to tell when UIWebView has finished displaying content

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit

I'm making a UIWebView load a pdf like this:

```
UIWebView *pdfView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
pdfView.delegate = self;
[pdfView loadRequest:request];
```

And then doing some stuff with the view once it loads:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)sender {
    [sender takeScreenshot]; // my UIView category screenshot method
    [sender release];
}
```

It all works, apart from the fact that at the point webViewDidFinishLoad is called, the view hasn't displayed anything yet, it displays a few milliseconds later. So is there any way to tell when the UIWebView has finished displaying its content (a pdf in this case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
[self performselector:@selector(getScreenshot) withObject:sender afterDelay:0.1];

-(void) getScreenshot:(UIWebView *)webView {
     [webView takeScreenshot];
     [webView release];
}
```

Or something similar.

Comment: i did consider something like this... seems very hacky though! who's to say what the right amount of time is?